# Enum rawvalue as AnyClass

Tags: ios, swift, class, enums

I know you can give enum's the rawvalue of String or Int ect but is there a way to make its type like AnyClass for example

```
enum Name:AnyClass{
    case classOne = ClassOne
    case classTwo = ClassTwo
}
```

Where ClassOne and ClassTwo are classes. The error I get is:

> Raw type 'AnyClass' is not convertable from any literal

So is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: What is your use case?  Sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: well the error occurs on the line enum Name:AnyClass. I'm just using it to test an instance for being a certain class

Comment: I know *why* the error occurs, but I'm asking why you want this.  Why not just do `object is ClassOne` or `type(of: object) == ClassOne.self`?

Answer (score 2):

> So is there another way to achieve this?

I do not know what "this" is, but as far as Swift syntax is concerned, the rule is straightforward. This:

```
enum Name:AnyClass {
```

is illegal. Only String and Int are allowed as raw value types (and only String and Int literals are allowed as case values).

Answer (score 0):

for example workaround

```
typealias MyTypeData = (title: String, iconName: String)
enum MyType: String {
    case Test1
    case Test2

    private var data: MyTypeData {
        switch self {
        case .Test1: return (title: "One", iconName: "icn1")
        case .Test2: return (title: "Two", iconName: "icn2")
        }
    }

    var title: String { get { return data.title } }
    var icon: UIImage? { get { return UIImage(named: data.iconName) } }

}
```

or you can try it

```
enum MyType: String {
     case Test1(data:OneClass)
     case Test2(data:TwoClass)
}
```