# How can I create enum from custom class in Swift

Tags: swift, enums

How can I create enum in swift from custom class, like this

```
class MyClass: NSObject {
    var identifier: String
    var title: String
    var iconName: String

    init(identifier: String, title: String, iconName: String) {
        super.init()
        self.identifier = identifier;
        self.title = title
        self.iconName = iconName
    }
}
```

example enum

```
enum MyType: MyClass {
        case Test1 = (identifier: "t1", title: "Test 1", iconName: "icn1")
        case Test2 = (identifier: "t2", title: "Test 2", iconName: "icn2")
}
```

But I have an error `not conform to RawRepresentable` and `not convert to Literal`

Comment: The raw type of an enum cannot be an arbitrary class, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41316815/enum-rawvalue-as-anyclass for a similar question with answer.

Comment: think about :  `MyType. Test1 == MyType. Test1` ?

Comment: That's not how enums work. However, you can define them with `static let` instead of `case` and you will be able to access them like this `MyType.Test1`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to declare enums in Swift of a particular class type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45502698/how-to-declare-enums-in-swift-of-a-particular-class-type)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my solution 1 finding on network

```
enum Devices: CGSize {
   case iPhone3GS = "{320, 480}"
   case iPhone5 = "{320, 568}"
   case iPhone6 = "{375, 667}"
   case iPhone6Plus = "{414, 736}"
}

extension CGSize: StringLiteralConvertible {
    public init(stringLiteral value: String) {
    let size = CGSizeFromString(value)
    self.init(width: size.width, height: size.height)
    }

    public init(extendedGraphemeClusterLiteral value: String) {
    let size = CGSizeFromString(value)
    self.init(width: size.width, height: size.height)
    }

    public init(unicodeScalarLiteral value: String) {
    let size = CGSizeFromString(value)
    self.init(width: size.width, height: size.height)
    }
}
```

and my solution 2 from my mind (workaround), this not init from class/struct but its has my data

```
typealias MyTypeData = (title: String, iconName: String)
enum MyType: String {
    case Test1
    case Test2

    private var data: MyTypeData {
        switch self {
        case .Test1: return (title: "One", iconName: "icn1")
        case .Test2: return (title: "Two", iconName: "icn2")
        }
    }

    var title: String { get { return data.title } }
    var icon: UIImage? { get { return UIImage(named: data.iconName) } }

}
```