# How to declare enums in Swift of a particular class type?

Tags: swift, enums

I am trying to create a class and use that class as the type for my new enum like shown below.

```
class Abc{
    var age  = 25
    var name = "Abhi"
}

enum TestEnum : Abc {
    case firstCase
    case secondCase
}
```

I am getting following error in playground .

```
error: raw type 'Abc' is not expressible by any literal
```

So i tried conforming to  RawRepresentable protocol like this.

```
extension TestEnum : RawRepresentable{
    typealias RawValue = Abc

    init?(rawValue:RawValue ) {
        switch rawValue {
        case Abc.age :
            self = .firstCase

        case Abc.name :
            self = .secondCase
        }
    }

    var rawValue : RawValue {
        switch self{

        case .firstCase :
            return Abc.age

        case .secondCase :
            return Abc.name
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting following errors after this :

```
error: raw type 'Abc' is not expressible by any literal
error: instance member 'age' cannot be used on type 'Abc'
error: instance member 'name' cannot be used on type 'Abc'
```

What is the proper way to declare enums of a certain class type, not getting clear idea on this. Anyone help?

Comment: `enum` is a value type while `class` is a reference type, so I don't think it's possible.

Comment: What you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: From the documentation: *"Raw values can be strings, characters, or any of the integer or floating-point number types"*

Comment: @MartinR, you can use custom types as raw values. See my answer.

Comment: Just like any other predefined types, i want an enum of my own type. A class type.

Comment: @KKbot please see my answer you can do it.

Comment: It still isn't clear exactly what you are trying to achieve. An enum is a type. Saying your want an enum of a class type is like saying you want a dog of cat type

Comment: @Paulw11 I agree with that. As a developer i am trying certain things on my own. Why we cant create an enum of a class type? Like this . .  enum SomeEnum : ClassType  ?

Comment: Because enums can't inherit from a class. It make no sense to even say that.  What would the semantics be?  A class can have a property which is a particular enum type

Comment: @Paulw11 its not inheritance. Whatever you write after : in enum is used as Raw value. See my answer how we can use our own class as raw value for enum.

Comment: @MohammadSadiq I know about raw values, but this doesn't seem to be what the OP is asking about (to be honest I still don't know what they are trying to do). Then again maybe they are asking about raw values, it's just that their raw value init also makes no sense.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From Docs

> In particular, the raw-value type must conform to the Equatable
>   protocol and one of the following protocols:
>   ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral for integer literals,
>   ExpressibleByFloatLiteral for floating-point literals,
>   ExpressibleByStringLiteral for string literals that contain any number
>   of characters, and ExpressibleByUnicodeScalarLiteral or
>   ExpressibleByExtendedGraphemeClusterLiteral for string literals that
>   contain only a single character.

So make your class Abc to conform to Equatable and one of the above mentioned protocols. Here is an example

```
public class Abc : Equatable,ExpressibleByStringLiteral{
    var age  = 25
    var name = "Abhi"
    public static func == (lhs: Abc, rhs: Abc) -> Bool {
        return (lhs.age == rhs.age && lhs.name == rhs.name)
    }
    public required init(stringLiteral value: String) {
        let components = value.components(separatedBy: ",")
        if components.count == 2 {
            self.name = components[0]
            if let age = Int(components[1]) {
                self.age = age
            }
        }
    }
    public required convenience init(unicodeScalarLiteral value: String) {
        self.init(stringLiteral: value)
    }
    public required convenience init(extendedGraphemeClusterLiteral value: String) {
        self.init(stringLiteral: value)
    }
}

enum TestEnum : Abc {
    case firstCase = "Jack,29"
    case secondCase = "Jill,26"
}
```

Now you can initialize your enum like

```
let exEnum = TestEnum.firstCase
print(exEnum.rawValue.name) // prints Jack
```

For detailed discussion and example you can refer 
https://swiftwithsadiq.wordpress.com/2017/08/21/custom-types-as-raw-value-for-enum-in-swift/

Comment: And how can I get a name from enum?

Comment: Why have you used this function "   ==  " ? Whats the purpose? How do you call it?

Comment: This is used to conform to Equatable protocol. That is one of the requirements for the class to be used as raw value.

Comment: to make a class equatable you need to declare operator == for it. As the class is going to be used as raw value system must know what cases are to be treated as equal.In this case two case having raw value with same name and same age will be considered equal though they might be of different instances.

Comment: You lost type checking and code completion by using string literals an created class with bunch of code just for simple thing like enum :), in swift we just go back in time haha

Comment: Michal's answer is definitely less complicated. This is a fun hack workaround though

Answer (score 18):

I'm not really sure what do you want to achieve, but take a look at my implementation, approach that I use in my projects:

```
class Abc {
    var age: Int
    var name: String

    init(age: Int, name: String) {
        self.age = age
        self.name = name
    }
}


enum TestEnum {
    case firstCase
    case secondCase

    var instance: Abc {
        switch self {
        case .firstCase: return Abc(age: 25, name: "John")
        case .secondCase: return Abc(age: 20, name: "Marry")
        }
    }
}

//Usage:

let abc = TestEnum.secondCase.instance
print(abc.age) //prints '20'
```

Comment: We can declare enums like this, enum SomeEnum : Int{  } or enum SomeEnum : String{ } . Why not like this enum SomeEnum : SomeClass{   } ?

Comment: To answer iPhoneDeveloper's question:  because each case of the enum essentially has to boil down to a String or an Int.  Mohamemed's answer above explains a complex way to do a declaration like you're saying and still have each case of the enum conform to those rules.  However, for code readability, I like Michal's answer better.  And it works.

Comment: Good stuff this is.

Comment: It will generate different Abc instance, each time.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Associated Values](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH12-ID148).
For your example:

```
class Abc {
    var age  = 25
    var name = "Abhi"
}

enum TestEnum {
    case age(Int)
    case name(String)
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
var person = Abc()
...
var value = TestEnum.age(person.age)

switch value {
    case .age(let age):
        print("Age: \(age).")
    case .name(let name):
        print("Name: \(name).")
}
```

And for convenience you can write extension for enum, that will take your `Abc` object and convert it to enum value:

```
static func fromAbc(_ object: Abc) -> TestEnum? {
    if object.age {
        return TestEnum.age(object.age)
    }

    if object.name {
        return TestEnum.name(object.name)
    }

    return nil
}
```

Note: in `func fromAbc(object: Abc) -> TestEnum?` you should replace conditions in if's to something that can be expressed as Bool (`age > 0`, etc).

As for the row values - in the [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH12-ID149) it is stated that

> Raw values can be strings, characters, or any of the integer or floating- point number types. Each raw value must be unique within its enumeration declaration.

And I'm not sure you can fit class there.

Comment: You can. See my answer.