# Using Class as RawValue of Enum not working

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, class, enums

I am trying to use my custom class **ChallengeUIElement** as rawValue of my enum **ChallengeUIElementType**.

Therefore, I tried everything that Xcode wanted me to do, but I still get error messages thrown right at my face. It starts to hurt...

Anyways, I followed along [this](https://swiftwithsadiq.wordpress.com/2017/08/21/custom-types-as-raw-value-for-enum-in-swift/) tutorial and get lots of error messages that I do not understand.

After googling for a while, I found some [stack overflow entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45502698/how-to-declare-enums-in-swift-of-a-particular-class-type) about classes as rawValue types of enums.

However, I still was unable to get my enum with class type working.

**My errors:**
[image: Errors]

**Here is my code:**

```
enum ChallengeUIElementType: ChallengeUIElement, CaseIterable {
    typealias RawValue = ChallengeUIElement

    case Default = "DefaultElementCell"
}

class ChallengeUIElement: Equatable, ExpressibleByStringLiteral {

    static func == (lhs: ChallengeUIElement, rhs: ChallengeUIElement) -> Bool {
        return lhs.identifier == rhs.identifier && lhs.height == rhs.height && lhs.type == rhs.type
    }

    var height: CGFloat
    var identifier: String
    var type: UICollectionViewCell.Type

    public init(stringLiteral value: String) {
        let components = value.components(separatedBy: ",")
        if components.count == 1 {
            if components[0] == "DefaultElementCell" {
                self.identifier = components[0]
                self.type = DefaultElementCell.self
                self.height = 380
            }
        }
    }

    public init(unicodeScalarLiteral value: String) {
        self.init(stringLiteral: value)
    }
    public init(extendedGraphemeClusterLiteral value: String) {
        self.init(stringLiteral: value)
    }
}
```

Also, I do not understand why I could use RawRepresentable as protocol with [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45502698/how-to-declare-enums-in-swift-of-a-particular-class-type), but not with [this one](https://swiftwithsadiq.wordpress.com/2017/08/21/custom-types-as-raw-value-for-enum-in-swift/)?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: _Why_ do you even want to use a class as a raw value type for an enum?  Maybe you actually need a dictionary of your enum as keys and the class as values?

Comment: @Sweeper Oh... that would make sense too. I think I'd go with that one. But what would be the typical use to use classes as a rawValue ?

Comment: That idea would never have come into my head, so I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors you get are mostly about the way you incorrectly declared your initialisers. They don't really have much to do with creating an enum with a class raw value.

Because your initialisers are required by the protocol, they need to be marked as `required`. You don't need to do this if your class is `final`. So either mark the class as `final` or mark all the initialisers as `required`.

The two convenience initialisers need to be marked as `convenience`:

```
public convenience init(unicodeScalarLiteral value: String) {
    self.init(stringLiteral: value)
}
public convenience init(extendedGraphemeClusterLiteral value: String) {
    self.init(stringLiteral: value)
}
```

These are "convenience" initialisers because they call another initialiser declared in the class.

Additionally, the `public init(stringLiteral value: String)` initialiser does not initialise all the properties. Think about what happens if the `if` statements are not run. You need to give your properties (`height`, `identifier` and `type`) some default values.