# Declare and enum of a custom type (type has multiple raw value types within it)

Tags: arrays, swift, enums

I have a custom struct type that contains multiple raw value types within it (some of which are custom enums):

```
struct Routes {

let routeTitle: String
let resortLocation: ResortLocations //<- Custom Enum
let distanceCategory: Distances //<- Custom Enum
let actualDistanceMiles: Double
let coordinates: [CLLocationCoordinate2D]

}
```

I will be creating many of these custom "Routes" types in a model, so right now, I have them stored in an array. I either reference them through regular indices

```
RouteArray.routes[0]
```

or with their titles:

```
for route in RouteArray {
  if route.routeTitle == "Route Name" {
     //use route
  }
}
```

But both of these seem inefficient to say the least. I wanted to try to set up an enum to do it instead:

```
enum RouteCatalog: Routes {
  case .routeName = //add in all the Routes information
}
```

but I get a few errors:

```
'RouteCatalog' declares raw type 'Routes', but does not conform to RawRepresentable and conformance could not be synthesized

Raw type 'Routes' is not expressible by a string, integer, or floating-point literal

RawRepresentable conformance cannot be synthesized because raw type 'Routes' is not Equatable
```

I know that I can make it conform to Equitable, and I know that there are other protocols that I can do like what is seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45502698/how-to-declare-enums-in-swift-of-a-particular-class-type) but given the amount of different types I have in my array, I guess I'm just confused as to what to do here.

Also, is there a better way to do this, or should I just keep iterating through the array as I currently am?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This doesn’t have anything to do with SwiftUI

Comment: Apologies.. I'm building this in SwiftUI and these are custom models that I have that are meant to be in addition to that. I'll remove the SwiftUI tag now.

Comment: I would say you are missing some thing in between the things you want to do has no meaning and use case.

Comment: swiftPunk I'm sorry I don't understand. Are you saying that I didn't phrase my question correctly?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a dictionary instead of an array and make an enum of your route titles (I assume this is the unique identifier for the struct) that you use as the key in the dictionary.

```
enum RouteName {
    case routeName
    case …
}
```

change the property declaration

```
let routeTitle: RouteName
```

(I didn’t use a raw value for the enum but if you need to display routeTitle then please do so)

And then keep your routes in a dictionary

```
Var routeCatalog: [RouteName: Routes]
```

Answer (score 1):

## Associated Values

There is a way to do something similar with "associated values". This isn't raw values but it does a great job.

```swift
enum ManyTypes {
    case integer(Int)
    case string(String)
    case anotherString(String)
    case customType(MyCustomType)
}
```

Then we can use a value of many types like this:

```swift
func useManyTypes(_ type: ManyType) {
    switch type {
    case .integer(let value): print("Integer \(value)")
    case .string(let value): print("string" + value)
...
```

Or you can go even further and use generics.

```swift
enum Either<Left, Right> {
    case left(Left)
    case right(Right)
}

func returnIntOrString(_ string: Bool) -> Either<Int, String> {
    string ? .right("This is a string") : .left(0)
}
```

For routing you can do something like :

```swift
enum Route {
    case `sheet`(AnyView)
    case fullScreen(AnyView)
    case popOver(AnyView)
    case navigate(AnyView)
}


@State var nextView: AnyView!
@State var shouldTransitionWithSheet = false

func handle(route: Route) {
    switch route:
    case .sheet(let view):
        self.nextView = view
        self.shouldTransitionWithSheet = true
    ....
}
```